# How to create JavaDoc with methods in ABC order

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, javadoc

I am creating a Javadoc for my library. Standard Android Javadocs have methods in ABC order (e.g. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

When I create my Javadoc in Android Studio (IntelliJ) the methods appear in order of appearance. Is there a way to change this so they appear in ABC order?

Note: I am referring to the 'Method Detail' section

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is default behavior for doclets but that you could create your own doclet using some other tools (listed in the 2nd link).

[Disable Alphabetic Sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169205/disable-alphabetically-sorting-in-javadoc)

[Create New Doclet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384646/how-to-create-java-documentation-in-order-of-appearance)